# Computing Correlations and p-values

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I have two vectors $A$ and $B$ of length (say) $50$ or so, and I want to determine whether there is any correlation between their entries. I computed their correlation directly and found it to be positive, but I also wanted to compute a $p$-value to confirm the implication that the entries are not completely independent.

However, when I asked *Mathematica* to compute the following:

> ```
> PearsonCorrelationTest[A, B, "TestDataTable"]
> ```

It gave an answer, but it also gave the following warning:

> PearsonCorrelationTest::nortst :  "At least one of the p-values in {0.508..., 0} resulting from a test for normality, is below 
>   0.025. The tests in {"PearsonCorrelation"} require that the data is 
>   normally distributed.

I couldn't find any further documentation on what *Mathematica* was doing. What assumptions on the vectors $A$ and $B$ is required for `PearsonCorrelationTest` to give a sensible answer?

Comment: It sounds like the data isn't normally distributed. Is that so? You might need to use something like `MannWhitneyTest` if that's the case.

Comment: Take a look at [this post](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3730/pearsons-or-spearmans-correlation-with-non-normal-data). It might help.

Comment: @RodLm, thanks for that, that's useful.

Comment: Pearson's correlation does assume Normality, while Spearman's correlation is a rank based correlation measure and does not assume Normality.

Comment: Since version 9 seems to have [`KendallTauTest[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/KendallTauTest.html) built-in, that's another possibility...

Comment: Or even `SpearmanRankTest[]`, why not?

Comment: @Shock, one vector is (something like) state population, in that it has a few "surprisingly big" points. The other might (roughly) be normal.

Comment: @Rod Lm, thanks for the link!

Comment: You means positive correlation exists among two vectors, but we have to check it is significant or not. Please use SPSS instead of Mathematica. Just enter your data in two columns and click Analyze-> correlate-> bivariate. Input variables in 'variables' and press ok. You get correlation and their significance value. In dialogue box other option also available, You can try them too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pearson's correlation **does assume** Normality, while Spearman's correlation is a rank based correlation measure and does not assume Normality.

So, instead of using `PearsonCorrelationTest[A, B, "TestDataTable"]` you should use

```
SpearmanRankTest[A, B, "TestDataTable"]
```

## EDITED

Pearson's correlation **does not assume** Normality, however the **sampling distribution** for Pearson's correlation does assume Normality.

Maybe that's why you're getting this error message from *Mathematica*.

Comment: Citing from the highest ranked answer in the link you posted above in comment yourself: *"It does not assume normality although it does assume finite variances and finite covariance"*. It looks like the jury is still out on this.

Comment: These assumptions must also be true for the Pearson correlation test...

Comment: I feel you're missing the part "does **not** assume normality" which is the opposite of what you write above.

Comment: OK, let me correct myself: the **sampling distribution** for Pearson's correlation does assume Normality, while the measure itself does not assume Normality. That's why on should use Spearman correlation instead of Pearson.